# Regex: replace all between two characters where no comma is included

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
++some+text+to+replace+stay,++some+text+to+replace+stay,++some+text+to+replace+stay
```

I want to replace everything between the `+` characters where no `,` is included.
So the result should look like:

```
_stay,_stay,_stay
```

("_" is the replaced space)

I've already played around a bit and got this working: 
    `(\+[^\,]+)(?=[^,](?:,|$))`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8VHsSsRTxTMIfX-9)

This is the closest I can get to the right result with my regex knowledge. Could you please help me out and explain your solution?

Comment: I have created this https://www.debuggex.com/r/0XFnQoDxDFgfs68_ it is quite self explanatory, but ask if you don't understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You started out right, but complicated everything. [Simply](https://www.debuggex.com/r/FC35VDFE_zAWA9hj):

```
\+[^,]+\+
```

A plus sign (`\+`), followed by anything that isn't a comma (`[^,]+`), followed by a plus sign (`\+`).

Comment: I thought I would have already tried this. Obviously not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
s.replace(/\+[^,]+(.{4})(?=,|$)/g, '_$1') // where `s` is the string
```

Comment: @Zulu Please use [this](https://regex101.com/r/kL6fU6/1) link. It can be shorten to `s.replace(/.+?(.{4})(?=(,|$))/g, '_$1$2')`;

Comment: Well actually `stay` was meant to be a placeholder. The actual value can differ in its length. So this approach does not work.